# powershell equivalent to netsh interface add excludedportrange

Tags: powershell, netsh

Is there a PowerShell command to exclude port ranges from an interface, as in the title of this question?

I can do it via netsh.exe

```
  netsh interface [ipv4|ipv6] add excludedportrange protocol=[udp|tcp] startport=<start> numberofports=<number> store=persistent
```

but can't google an equivalent for PowerShell.

Comment: There is no reason not to use exactly what you have in a PS script. Many times, old school is the most prudent option

Comment: Sure, that's what I now do.  But netsh does warn "In future versions of WIndows, Microsoft might remove the Netsh functionality for TCP/IP"

Comment: Netsh also says "Type Get-Command -Module NetTCPIP" but I can't find the answer there nor did a web search return anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Extending from my comment. You could use the `New-NetFirewallRule` cmdlet to accomplish what you are after.

See:

- [New-NetFirewallRule (NetSecurity) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/new-netfirewallrule?view=windowsserver2022-ps)
- ['powershell equiv to netsh'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell%20equiv%20to%20netsh%27&t=h_&ia=web)

So, stuff maybe like this will get you there:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Exclude Port Range 3000-3050" -Direction Outbound -Protocol TCP -LocalPort 3000-3050 -Action Block
```

See cmdlet examples and details here:

```
Get-Help -Name New-NetFirewallRule -Examples
Get-Help -Name New-NetFirewallRule -Detail
```

As you will see in the docs, the `-Protocol` parameter can be used to specify a different protocol (such as UDP).

Use the `-RemoteAddress` parameter for target IP address/range.

***Update***

Using the `New-NetFirewallPortFilter` cmdlet.

> https://duckduckgo.com/?q=New-NetFirewallPortFilter&t=h_&ia=web

The closest you can get to that netsh command you are using is maybe something like this:

```
<#
create a new set of firewall rules that excludes a specific range of ports
on TCP and UDP.
#>

New-NetFirewallPortFilter -Protocol TCP -StartPort <start> -NumberOfPorts <number> -Store persistent
    
New-NetFirewallPortFilter -Protocol UDP -StartPort <start> -NumberOfPorts <number> -Store persistent
```

Or this way for a one-liner

```
('TCP', 'UDP').ForEach({New-NetFirewallPortFilter -Protocol $PSItem -StartPort <start> -NumberOfPorts <number> -Store persistent})
```

Comment: It doesn't look like -Action Block does the same as netsh's excludeportrange.  Block is a firewall rule to drop packets to specific ports. Excludeportrange prevents programs that request a random port to get a port in that range, i.e. they need to be explicitly requested.

Comment: You can set Windows Firewall (Adv Sec) to block programs from requesting a random port, but you'd have to do that per program.